# How can I clear item in cart with onClick in react?

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to create a button that delete item in cart with react

here is my cart.js:

```
const Cart = ({ basketProps }) => {
  const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
  let productsInCart = [];

  if (basketProps.inCart) {
    productsInCart = basketProps.products;
  } else {
    productsInCart = [];
  }

  let shippingFee = 25000;
  let additionalShippingFee = 15000;
  let totalPrice = shippingFee + additionalShippingFee + basketProps.cartCost;

  const clearProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Container>
        <Info>There are 1 items in your Shopping Bag.</Info>
        <Info>
          <LinkShop to="/">Shop more</LinkShop> or{" "}
          <LinkShop to="/">Check out now</LinkShop>
        </Info>
        {productsInCart.map((product, i) => (
          <ProductInfo key={i}>
            <Infor>
              <Image src={product.img_url1} />
            </Infor>
            <Infor>
              <ProductTitle>{product.title}</ProductTitle>
              <ProductPrice>
                <ProductQuantity>{product.quantity} x </ProductQuantity>
                {nf.format(product.price)} vnd
                <RemoveButton type="submit" onClick={clearProduct}>
                  Remove
                </RemoveButton>
              </ProductPrice>
            </Infor>
            {productsInCart.length > 1 ? <LineDivide /> : null}
          </ProductInfo>
        ))}
}
```

How can I create a button to clear that specific product in my cart?
Here is my github project if you want to look over my code:

https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Thank you!

Updated code:

Here is my update code from reducer:

```
case DELETE_SOME_ITEM:
    let items = state.products.filter(itemDelete => itemDelete.id !== action.payload)
    console.log(items)
    return {
        ...state,
        items: state.products.filter(itemDelete => itemDelete.id !== action.payload)
    };
```

when i console.log(items) it return for me all items in my cart not specific item i clicked on

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it'll works in your case(there aren't enought data), but you can try to use `array.filter()` method for this task. If you are using `array.map()` for items render and every item have some `id` - try to create another action for item deletion and pass an `id` to ur reducer. Than `filter()` state. For example:

```
action:
export const deleteItem = (id) => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_SOME_ITEM', payload: id})

reducer:
case 'DELETE_SOME_ITEM':
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.filter(itemToDelte) => itemToDelete.id !== action.payload,
}
```

It will works with your local array too. Just create some handler function which will return result of `productsInCart.filter()`